# Magento - Validate Email in Database with AJAX without refresh

Tags: ajax, database, validation, magento, checkout

I’m beginner in Magento and I’m with a QuickCheckout Form, where I need to validate the e-mail field.

When the user put the e-mail on the field I need to search in the database (table customer_entity) the e-mail dynamically, without refresh

I have code using Ajax.Request that works to validate the writing of e-mail using regular expressions

```
function validar_email() { 
  local = "billing";

  var urlAjax = location.href;
  var validarUrl = /^https:\/\//;

  if ( urlAjax.match( validarUrl ) ) {
    urlAjax = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl("link", true)."ajaxend/ajax" ?>';
  } else {
    urlAjax = '<?php echo $this->getUrl("ajaxend/ajax") ?>';
  }

  new Ajax.Request( urlAjax, {method: 'POST',
                parameters: 'email='+$(local+':email').value,
                evalScripts: true,
                onLoading: function(transport) {

                 $('load-email-'+local).innerHTML = 'Verificando E-mail';
                },
                onSuccess: function(transport) {

                                    var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2}/;
                            var emailValido = 'E-mail Válido';
                            var emailInvalido = 'E-mail Inválido, digite outro';
                            if( !emailReg.test($(local+':email').value)){
                                $('load-email-'+local).innerHTML = emailInvalido;
                            } else {
                                $('load-email-'+local).innerHTML = emailValido;
                            }

                },
                onComplete: function(transport) {

                },


                onFailure: function() { /*document.getElementById("...").innerHTML = 'problemas...';*/ }


              });
}
```

I made two pieces of code to search in Database: 
Code 1:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');


    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    $table = $resource->getTableName('customer_entity');

    $query = 'SELECT email FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE email = "'.$email.'";';

    $sku = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

Code 2 (only PHP):

```
$queryVerifEmail = '';
$queryVerifEmail .= ' SELECT email FROM customer_entity';
$queryVerifEmail .= ' WHERE email = "'.$email.'";';

$result = mysql_query($queryVerifEmail);
```

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1){
  echo $email.' já existe na base!'; } else{ echo $email.'valido'; }
```

I tried to make referenced php files in the line

```
new Ajax.Request( "getEmail.php?", {method: 'GET',
```

And nothing works, but Ajax.Request is the only way to make working Inputs without refresh in Magento

I want to have the best solution that you know, but I don´t want to buy or install new modules for it, I want a code solution, be in Ajax, JQuery or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this task using jQuery autocomplete
From ajax request you can retrieving data from the database and convert in to json array and display suggestions

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/